# adb Wi-Fi pairing is infinite

Tags: android-studio

Adb Wi-Fi pairing works fine almost all the time. But sometimes I stuck at infinite loading when trying to Wi-Fi pair. After a few minutes it shows the error to try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Possible solutions

- Reboot your phone
- Disable and enable Wi-Fi debugging
- Disable and enable Wi-Fi
- Restart ADB server

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not just restart adb via command line?

Comment: @CoolMind, You are right. I should also add this way to the answer. The problem is that path to adb can be different for every user

Comment: Agree with you. Android developers should have a path to adb, as it is widely used (install adb, set permissions, restart, copy files, etc.). But your way is interesting too, I didn't know it.